# Selection on listbox does not bring data as required.<<ListboxSelect>> error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a module where User will enter Reference Number and Quantity of a product. Program will fetch ItemName on base of Reference number from Database and will insert both ItemName and Quantity to the Listbox. On selecting Listbox item, the same will be added to a label,  but selecting on Listbox brings only ItemName into Label,not quantity. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

root = Tk()

# root.state('zoomed')

root.geometry('550x450')


def add():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Grocery.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    sel = cur.execute('select StockAvailable,ItemName from StockDetails where ItemRef=?', 
    (EntPro.get(),))
    for stoc in sel:
        lis = stoc[0]
    lis = int(lis)
    stoc = int(EntQty.get())
    upd = lis - stoc
    cur.execute('update StockDetails set StockAvailable=? where ItemRef=?', (upd, EntPro.get()))
    a = cur.execute('select ItemName from StockDetails where ItemRef=?', (EntPro.get(),))
    for i in a:
        j=str(i)
        ProList.insert(0, j,str(''),EntQty.get())
    conn.commit()


def design():
    global EntPro, EntQty, ProList, QtyList, SelPro, SelQty
    EntPro = Entry(root)
    EntPro.place(x=0, y=0)

    EntQty = Entry(root)
    EntQty.place(x=0, y=50)

    BtnAdd = Button(root, text='Add', command=add)
    BtnAdd.place(x=0, y=100)

    FrameList = Frame(root, width=800, height=400)
    FrameList.place(x=150, y=0)

    scroll = Scrollbar(FrameList)
    scroll.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')

    ProList = Listbox(FrameList, width=35, height=25, yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    ProList.grid(row=0, column=0)
    ProList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', select)

    QtyList = Listbox(FrameList, width=20, height=25, yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    QtyList.grid(row=0, column=1)
    QtyList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', select)

    scroll.config(command=ProList.yview)
    scroll.config(command=QtyList.yview)

    SelPro = StringVar()
    Label(root, textvariable=SelPro, relief='groove', width=20).place(x=0, y=150)

    SelQty = StringVar()
    Label(root, textvariable=SelQty, relief='groove', width=20).place(x=0, y=200)


def select(event):
    global sd
    p = ProList.curselection()[0]
    sd = ProList.get(p)
    SelPro.set(sd[0])
    SelQty.set(sd[1])


design()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Post the full error code please

Comment: It doesn't return any error, it just does not show data in labels as desired.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that your functions are being called? Have you verified that `sd` is what you think it is? Have you verified that you're setting the values you think you're setting?

Comment: `sd` is a string, so `sd[0]` and `sd[1]` are the first and second character of `sd` respectively.  I wonder why you can get the full `ItemName`.